# Powershell -lt and -gt giving opposite of expected results

Tags: powershell, get-wmiobject

In the below code, if I add a where-object,  -lt & -gt are giving opposite of expected results.

I'm sure the reason is I'm stupid, but in what specific way am I messing up?

This part gives the expected results, where in my case, the single drive has %Free of 39.8

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2 -Class win32_logicaldisk | where-object -Property drivetype -eq 3 | 
format-table deviceid,
@{n='GB Capacity';e={$_.size/1gb}},
@{n='GB Free';e={$_.freespace/1gb}},
@{n='%Free';e={($_.freespace/$_.size)*100}}
```

But adding this

```
| where {$_.'%Free' -gt 10}
```

Results in no output.  In fact

```
| where {$_.'%Free' -gt 0}
```

Produces no results.  Instead I have to use

```
| where {$_.'%Free' -lt 0}
```

Powershell thinks %Free is a negative number, I guess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are piping `Format-Table` to anything. You should never use that except to output to the screen. Using `Format-Table` outputs everything as a format object, not whatever was piped into it. Instead use `Select-Object` to get what you need.

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2 -Class win32_logicaldisk | where-object -Property drivetype -eq 3 | 
Select-Object deviceid,
@{n='GB Capacity';e={$_.size/1gb}},
@{n='GB Free';e={$_.freespace/1gb}},
@{n='%Free';e={($_.freespace/$_.size)*100}}
```

Comment: Doh!  I didn't even realize I'd done that.  Exactly what I needed, thanks!